# Neo4j cypher ALL IN

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following Cypher query:

```
MATCH (genre:Genre)<-[:BELONGS_TO]-(t:Title) 
WHERE genre.name IN ["Comedy", "Drama"] 
RETURN t
```

Which returns titles that belong to Comedy `OR` Drama genres.
How to change this query in order to return all titles that belong to Comedy `AND` Drama genres?

Comment: on the documentation is an example:
WHERE n.name = 'Peter' XOR (n.age < 30 AND n.name = 'Timothy') OR NOT (n.name = 'Timothy' OR n.name = 'Peter')
Source: https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/where/

may that helps.

Comment: I apologize, but I still don't see how to achieve it

Comment: Maybe with: where genre.name = "Comedy" AND genre.name = "Drama"

Comment: No, it doesn't work

Comment: ahh i see. sorry. You need to change to this maybe:
MATCH (t:Title)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(genre:Genre)<-[:BELONGS_TO]-(t) 

t is an alias to the same node. genre can be in [...] so it should work

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: What about:
```
MATCH (:Genre {name: 'Comedy'})<-[:BELONGS_TO]-(t:Title)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(:Genre {name: 'Drama'})
RETURN t 
```

Or do you want a query that works for any number of genres?

Comment: Thanks, Rolf! Yes, I need to provide a dynamic genre collection of any size(based on user input from the UI) so I prefer to not hardcode the genres in the query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SIZE` is your friend.

```
MATCH (t:Title)-[:BELONGS_TO]->(g:Gender) 
WHERE g.name IN ["Comedy", "Drama"] 
WITH t, COLLECT(g) AS g
WHERE SIZE(g) >= x
RETURN t
```

`x` - is number of elements in IN clause